# Appending a specific value to a column in MS Access

Tags: ms-access

I've got a little issue in MS Access... I'm sure it's really easy to be solved, but as I'm still an aprendice, I decided to ask (:

Let's supose I have a table like this:

```
      Name       |   Country   |   Grades   |   IDNumber    |  Identifier
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Scott            |    USA      | 8, 9, 10   |     1000      |  
Wolverine        |  Indonesia  | 2, 5, 7    |     2000      |  
Nightcrawler     |   Brazil    | 10, 0, 6   |     3000      |  
Jean Grey        |   China     | 10, 10, 10 |     4000      |  
Bobby            |   China     | 8, 7, 10   |     5000      |  
Kitty            |    USA      | 9, 9, 9    |     6000      |
```

I want a APPEND query that appends a value passed by me, to my "Identifier" column.
Can someone help me?

```
I would like to get an out like:

      Name       |   Country   |   Grades   |   IDNumber    |  Identifier
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Scott            |    USA      | 8, 9, 10   |     1000      |  Automatic
Wolverine        |  Indonesia  | 2, 5, 7    |     2000      |  Automatic
Nightcrawler     |   Brazil    | 10, 0, 6   |     3000      |  Automatic
Jean Grey        |   China     | 10, 10, 10 |     4000      |  Automatic
Bobby            |   China     | 8, 7, 10   |     5000      |  Automatic
Kitty            |    USA      | 9, 9, 9    |     6000      |  Automatic
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use an update query, not an append.  An append query adds in new records, it will not edit existing ones.  Do something like:

```
UPDATE YourTableName SET Identifier='Automatic'
```

This will update all the records' Identifier field to "Automatic" like in your example.  If you only want to update certain records, add in a `WHERE` clause to the end (i.e. `WHERE Country='USA'`)